# Problema con bluetooth en slackware 14.2 current

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Luego de haber actualizado el kernel a la versión 4.4.6, tanto el GUI del bluetooth como algunas otras cosas (por ej. el conectar un dispositivo por bluetooth) no funcionan.

Las cosas que probé fueron las siguientes:

- reinstalar el package de bluetooth (blueman) sin éxito
- tampoco desinstalarlo y volverlo a instalar
- reiniciar el servicio

Siendo usuario me da:

```
Starting Bluetooth services: 

 bluetoothd hciconfig sdptool hciattach D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.58" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
rfcomm
```

Y siendo root lo inicia bien sin error o con sudo también lo inicia bien.

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[ 6.623881] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[ 6.623897] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 6.623901] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 6.623903] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 6.623908] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 15.270804] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 15.270808] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 15.270812] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

hcitool dev
Devices:
hci0 4C:EB:42:7F:C1:6D


rfkill list bluetooth
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

ya no sé qué probar, antes funcionaba genial, pero ahora no, y no tengo intención de hacer downgrade!

Comment: Supongo que intentaste arrancarlo como root ¿cierto?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu mismo iniciaste un hilo [aquí](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?s=17285164c3a25072873330b723468c8e&p=5525317#post5525317) dónde explican la solución (y la expongo para futuras referencias) que se acerca mucho a lo que ya comentabas en tu pregunta pero con un orden concreto que es muy importante mantener:

1. Para el proceso de `bluetoothf` con:

> /etc/rc.d/rc.bluetooth stop

2. Elimina el paquete `bluez`

> removepkg bluez

3. Reinstala el paquete `bluez`:

> slackpkg update
>
> slackpkg install bluez
>
> /etc/rc.d/rc.bluetooth start

Y solucionado.

Además cuándo haces el paso 2 de eliminar el  `bluez` te aparecerán muchos mensajes (no te preocupes por eso) que pueden ser informativos por si hay algún error pero aunque sea así, mientres se desinstale, no importa.