# ¿Cómo insertar código fuente en Ms Word?

Tags: ide, ms-word

¿Cómo puedo copiar un **código fuente** dentro de un documento de *Microsoft Word* de forma que el código permanezca con el **formato** de una IDE, o al menos con un formato similar?

Por formato entiendase, destaques (como negritas, coloración de palabras clave, etc.) que las IDEs realizan en el código. En ingles es conocido como *highlighting*.

Debe existir alguna forma de que el *Ms Word* importe el archivo de texto, tal vez de una IDE como *Ms Visual Studio* manteniendo el formato, colocando numeración de lineas, etc.

O talvez exista una forma de exportar de la IDE, el código con el formato destacado debidamente.

Los intentos que realice fueron:

1. Intentar copiar como imagen, lo que dificulta mucho la manipulación del código.
2. Otro intento fue insertar un archivo de texto dentro de un cuadro de texto. Pero además de perder el formato de la IDE, el texto insertado es una copia del original y no consigo impedir la modificación del código dentro del documento de Ms Word.

Comment: ¿Cuando dices "__formato__ de una IDE", te refieres a usar un ["tipo de letra monoespaciado"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_letra_monoespaciado) o a algo más  complejo que pretendes lograr programáticamente?

Comment: Me refiero a los _highlighting_, los *destaques* que realizan las IDE. Resaltar palabras, reconocer comentarios, etc

Comment: ¿Quieres programar en Visual Basic para Aplicaciones un __resaltador de código__? Si no vas a programar nada y solo quieres copiar y pegar visita este sitio: https://tohtml.com/ y deberías cerrar esta pregunta que no tiene nada que ver con programación.

Comment: Creo que si bien la pregunta no tenga a ver com programación. Tiene mucho a ver con las necesidades de estudiantes de programación. Mi pregunta es genuina, e la respuesta seria muy util a muchas personas. Tanto estudiantes de programación como estudiantes de maestria y doctorado como es mi caso. En Stackoverflow existen muchas preguntas que no tienen a ver con programación. Este es un ejemplo: [Problema con bluetooth en slackware 14.2 current](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6464/problema-con-bluetooth-en-slackware-14-2-current). Esa pregunta no tiene a ver con programación,

Comment: ¿Y ya intentaste la sugerencia que te hice? ¿Ya fuiste al sitio que te menciono?

Comment: Si, fue una sugerencia útil. Vote a favor inclusive. Y además descubri como colocar numeración de lineas en word Mas pienso que puede haber otras soluciones también. Inclusive soluciones que envuelvan la exportación del código de la IDE. Que talvez permitan mantener el mismo estilo y la numeración. Creo que la pregunta puede ajúdar a mais programadores y que pueden existir mais respuestas.